# Python Regex: get everything except for string

Tags: python, regex

I have the following sentence:

```
Graft Concepts has partnered with\u00a0several sites\u00a0to offer customization options for backplates, so customers will be able to design their own with\u00a0
```

I'd like to get rid of all instances of "\u00a0", whether or not they are connected to other words, e.g. "with\u00a0several"

How would I do this using regex with python? I've tried experimenting with re.compile() and re.findall(), but I couldn't get this working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use `.replace`:

```
s = s.replace('\\u00a0', ' ')
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it works, but how would I do this with Regex?

Comment: `s = re.sub(r'\\u00a0', ' ', s)`

Answer (score 0):

This works under Python 2:

```
import re

st='''Graft Concepts has partnered with\u00a0several sites\u00a0to offer customization options for backplates, so customers will be able to design their own with\u00a0''' 

st=re.sub(ur'\\u00a0','',st,re.UNICODE)
```

And this under Python 3:

```
st=re.sub(u'\\u00a0','',st,re.UNICODE)
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if the OP had literal `\u00a0` in the string or actual Unicode U+00A0 characters. The comment to my answer suggests the former.

Comment: I used his literal text. Those backslashes multiply, no?